# docker ps: show command with environment variables resolved

Tags: docker, environment-variables

docker ps: how to show command with environment variables resolved

```
> docker ps --no-trunc
```

command contains `${ENV_VARIABLE}`.

Comment: An entrypoint wrapper script could modify the environment variables before it actually runs that command, and since an actual shell typically processes the command string the substitution and splitting rules have come complexity.  I'm not sure this is possible in general.  On a Linux host not running Docker Desktop you could find the actual process with ps(1) and you might be able to get more information that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$ docker inspect CONTAINER_ID --format='{{.Config.Env}}'
```

Comment: env variables inside container can be overridden by those in .env and shell, right? So the env variables resolved for a command can be different.

Comment: @eastwater ... what?

Comment: You are right. the ENVs in container are not affected by shell.